# Asynchronous shiny programming - setting up a basic example

Tags: r, shiny

As an exercise, I have modified the default Old Faithful Geyser Data app to incorporate asynchronous programming. However it's behaviour doesn't satisfy my expectations based on my understanding of asynchronous programming I suspect there is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Here, the app creates 2 plot outputs that are identical. One takes longer than the other but set up to work asynchronously, the other is fast.

**server.R**

```
library(future)
library(promises)
library(shiny)
plan(multisession)

function(input, output) {

    bins = reactive({
        future({
            print("I'm slow")
            Sys.sleep(10)
            faithful[, 2]
        }) %...>% 
        {seq(min(.), max(.), length.out = input$slow_bins + 1)}
    })

    output$slow_dist_plot <- renderPlot({
        bins() %...>%
        {hist(faithful[, 2], breaks = ., col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')}

    })

    output$fast_dist_plot = renderPlot({
        print("I'm fast")
        x    <-faithful[, 2] 
        bins = seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$fast_bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("slow_bins",
                        "Number of slow bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30),
            sliderInput('fast_bins',
                        'fast bins',
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("slow_dist_plot"),
            plotOutput("fast_dist_plot")
        )
    )
)
```

Based on my understanding of asynchronous programming mainly derived from [this](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/06/26/shiny-1-1-0/) Rstudio post, if two users are running this code at the same time, after the initial plotting of the two plots, if one of the users change the slow bins the other user should be free to play around with the fast bins and get instant plots as the other users request is processed by a new process.

However when I actually try this with two windows, I see that whenever I make a change in the slow bin, the other windows have to wait for slow bins to complete. What is going wrong here? Are my expectations wrong or did I set this up wrongly?

Comment: I think that in Shiny open source edition only one R instance responds to the various users. So one have to wait the calculation to end to do the other calculation.

Comment: I believe that applies to users showing up to the site for the first time. My understanding is, `future` and `promises` packages are specifically designed to remedy the "one session many users" problem

Comment: Looks like you are right.

Comment: @OganM you are correct in your thinking. And that is actually the behaviour I see. Maybe try updating the packages...?

Comment: Hmm... Everything is up to date other than R (3.4.4) however this does seem to be machine specific. Running through a local rstudio works fine but my Rstudio server shows the weird behavior. Trying to pinpoint a difference

Comment: I have pinpointed the difference to the way future works in the two machines. May delete this and open a new question here. For now there is an rstudio community question here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/debugging-behaviour-of-future-in-different-machines/16580

Comment: And now an SA question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865362/future-waits-for-execution-on-single-core-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected behaviour in the question is correct. However, on a single core machine, the number of workers is set to 1 by default when using `multisession` plan. Doing

```
plan(multisession,workers = 2)
```

will have the expected behaviour. Raising the number is probably necessary for an app in live use.