# future waits for execution on single-core machine

Tags: r, asynchronous, future, r-future

I have 2 machines with identical versions of Ubuntu (16.04), R (3.4.4) and the future package (1.10.0). I am running the code below, that implements asyncronous programming

```
tic()
library(future)
plan(multisession)
mehAsync = function(){
    future::future({
        Sys.sleep(5)
        return('meh')
    })
}
out = mehAsync()
what = then(out,function(value){(value)})
toc()
```

The expected behaviour is that the execution will end almost instantly, leaving what to be a pending promise. In one machine this happens, the execution happens instantly. However in another machine I have, the execution waits for the mehAsync function to execute, finishing after 5 seconds.

As stated before, both machines are almost identical. The key difference between them is that the slower one is a single core machine. However based on my understanding, the `multisession` plan shouldn't require multiple cores. Just enough resources to open a new R session which the machine has.

The specific questions here are:

- Is my understanding of the expected behaviour wrong and this is normal for a single core machine?
- What other factors that I am not taking into account could be effecting this behaviour?
- How can I debug this issue as there are no error/warning messages and can't be replicated by myself and other people in independent machines?

Note: this question came up when trying to investigate [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864035/asynchronous-shiny-programming-setting-up-a-basic-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default options for the `multisession` plan sets the `workers` parameters to  `availableCores()` in a single core machine. Which means if one does not override the parameters when using `plan`, the number of cores does matter.

Doing

```
plan(multisession,workers=2)
```

solves this issue